# E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null; What am I doing wrong

Tags: android

My main activity java.  The app is working but if I shake my android device, it does not show me the advert.  My logcat is saying my Sensor or listener is null.  When I shake my phone nothing happens.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    MagicAnswer mMagicAnswer;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager manager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private TextView textView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensorAccelerometer;
    private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
    private TextView mAnswerTV;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mAnswerTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mMagicAnswer = new MagicAnswer(MapsActivity.this);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                displayMagicAnswer();
            }

            private void displayMagicAnswer() {
                String magicAnswer = mMagicAnswer.getRandomAnswer();
                mAnswerTV.setText(magicAnswer);
            }


        });

        Thread myThread = null;

        Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
        myThread = new Thread(runnable);
        myThread.start();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        TextView txtCurDateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_yes);
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
        txtCurDateTime.setText(datetime);


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        //get the location service
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //request the location update thru location manager
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //get the latitude and longitude from the location
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                //get the location name from latitude and longitude
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses =
                            geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String result = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality() + ":";
                    result += addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ":";
                    result += addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mSensorAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        //LatLng Tandragee = new LatLng(6, 53);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Tandragee).title("Marker in Tandragee"));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Tandragee));
    }

    public void onSensorChange(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        manager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        Log.i("onPause...", "paused");
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector, mSensorAccelerometer);

    }


    public void doWork() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TextView txtCurrentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main);
                    Date dt = new Date();
                    int hours = dt.getHours();
                    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                    String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                    txtCurrentDate.setText(curTime);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }


    class CountDownRunner implements Runnable {
        // @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    doWork();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: ShakeDetector is not a built in part of Android.  We have no idea what library you're using or how its implemented, so we can't really answer your question.